# Karp hardness of two vertex sets in a digraph

Tags: graphs, np-complete, np-hard, np

Given a digraph $G(V,A)$ and a number $k$, we want to find two vertex subsets $S,T\subseteq V$ such that:

1. $|S|+|T|=k$
2. For every $v\notin S\cup T$, $v$ has no arcs coming to $S$, and no arcs coming from $T$. In other words, from $v$'s point of view, $S$ is the source, $T$ is the terminal. Hence their names.

So, can this be solved by an efficient algorithm or it is NP-complete?

Comment: Can $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Yes, $S\cap T\neq\emptyset$ can appear in a feasible solution.